# Define lambda calculus encoding for boolean implication (⇒)

Tags: lambda-calculus

how to define lambda calculus encoding for boolean implication(⇒). (Recall that in boolean logic, x ⇒ y iff ¬x ∨ y.) You may use **true**, **false** and **cond** by name in your definitions if you want.

true := λx. λy. x

false := λx. λy. y

cond := λb. λx. λy. b x y

I currently have got `"not" := λx.x false true`
                      `"or" := λx.λy.x true y`
What should I do next ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86157/discussion-on-question-by-student-define-lambda-calculus-encoding-for-boolean-im).

Answer (score 2):

Let me go through how you might come up with the formula for `or`, and then let you do something similar for `impl`.

The key observation here is: if $x$ is true, then $x \vee y$ is always true.  Whereas if $x$ is false, then $x \vee y$ is equal to $y$.  Therefore,
$x \vee y = cond ~ x ~ true ~ y.$  In other words, $$\vee = \lambda x . \lambda y . (\mathbf{if}~ x~ \mathbf{then}~ true ~ \mathbf{else}~ y) = \lambda x . \lambda y . cond ~ x ~ true ~ y = \lambda x . \lambda y . x ~ true ~ y.$$  (And if you like, you can then make this a bit shorter using the $\eta$ rule: it is equivalent to $\lambda x . x ~ true$.)

Now, for `impl`, we can start off with a similar analysis: if $x$ is true, then $x \rightarrow y$ is equal to $y$; whereas if $x$ is false, then $x \rightarrow y$ is always true.  I'll leave it to you to take the construction of `impl` as a lambda expression from here.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured that out.